# Implementing Object-specific Color Change in React Native App Using computer vision from API

Tags: javascript, react-native, image-processing, graphics, drawing

I'm building a React Native app where users can preview an image of a room and change the color of certain objects like the walls, floor, and ceiling. I'm using an API which provides the data for these objects, including their contour points, but I'm not sure how to apply the color change to specific objects only. Can anyone guide me on how I could achieve this?

Here the link for the docs on the API I'm suing [https://vision-api.wizart.ai/?\_gl=1](https://vision-api.wizart.ai/?%5C_gl=1)

[Here is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2cf.gif)

here is the response I'm getting from the API (The data i'm getting is from the /interior endpoint)

`{"analysis": {"camera": {"fov": 68.1892181283756, "height": 1.5, "pitch": -0.041640043476766975, "roll": 0.04751349899879592}, "image_info": {"bad_target_confidence": 0.9999918937683105, "blurry_confidence": 0.8775407671928406, "dark_confidence": 0.9995574355125427, "noisy_confidence": 0.988041877746582}, "interior_type": "bedroom"}, "detection": {"ceiling": {"points": [Array]}, "floor": {"points": [Array]}, "walls": [[Object], [Object]], "windows": [[Object]]}, "reconstruction": {"ceiling": {"area": 0, "points": [Array]}, "floor": {"area": 8.519802858043203, "points": [Array]}, "walls": [[Object], [Object]]}, "segmentation": {"mask": null, "vectorized_masks": {"ceiling": [Object], "floor": [Object], "walls": [Object]}}}`

here's how I'm trying to parse the data in my imagePreview component

```
import {RouteProp, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {RootStackParamList} from './Tabs';
import {useVisionObjects} from './hooks/useVisionObjects';
import { Svg, Polygon } from 'react-native-svg';

type ImagePreviewScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList,'ImagePreview'>;
type Point = { x: number; y: number; };

type Mask = {
  contours: Point[][];
  hierarchy: any[];
};
type VectorizedMasks = {
  ceiling: Mask;
  floor: Mask;
  walls: Mask;
};


const ImagePreview = () => {
  const route = useRoute<ImagePreviewScreenRouteProp>();
  

  if (!route.params) {
    return null;
  }

  const imageSource = route.params.Image;
  const visionObjects = useVisionObjects(imageSource);
  
  if (
    !visionObjects ||
    !visionObjects.vectorizedMasks ||
    visionObjects.imgWidth === null ||
    visionObjects.imgHeight === null
  ) {
    return null;
}
  
const {vectorizedMasks, imgWidth, imgHeight} = visionObjects;
  
  const covertToPixels = (point: Point, imgWidth: number, imgHeight: number)  => {
  
    const x = point.x * imgWidth;
    const y = point.y * imgHeight;
   
    return {x, y}
  }

  const wallsInPixels = {
    ceiling: {
      contours: vectorizedMasks.ceiling.contours.map(contour => {
        return contour.map(point => covertToPixels(point, imgWidth, imgHeight));
      }),
      hierarchy: vectorizedMasks.ceiling.hierarchy
    },
    floor: {
      contours: vectorizedMasks.floor.contours.map(contour => {
        return contour.map(point => covertToPixels(point, imgWidth, imgHeight));
      }),
      hierarchy: vectorizedMasks.floor.hierarchy
    },
    walls: {
      contours: vectorizedMasks.walls.contours.map(contour => {
        return contour.map(point => covertToPixels(point, imgWidth, imgHeight));
      }),
      hierarchy: vectorizedMasks.walls.hierarchy
    }
};

  const ObjectPainter: React.FC<{ vectorizedMasks: VectorizedMasks }> = ({ vectorizedMasks }) => {
    const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState('red');

    const contoursToSvg = (contours: Point[][] ) => {
      return contours.map((contour, index) => {
        const points = contour.map(point => `${point.x},${point.y}`).join(' ');
        return <Polygon key={index} points={points} fill={selectedColor} onPress={() => setSelectedColor('blue')} />;
      });
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: imageSource}} />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return <ObjectPainter vectorizedMasks={wallsInPixels} />;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  img: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 9 / 16,
  },
});

export default ImagePreview;
```

Here's how I'm making the request

```
import { RouteProp, useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import  {  useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { RootStackParamList } from "../Tabs";
import { API_KEY, AUTH_TOKEN, BASE_URL } from '@env'

type ImagePreviewScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'ImagePreview'>;

type PointType = { x: number; y: number; };
type MaskType = { contours: PointType[][], hierarchy: any[] };

export const useVisionObjects = (imageSource: string) => {
    const route = useRoute<ImagePreviewScreenRouteProp>();
    const [vectorizedMasks, setVectorizedMasks] = useState<{ ceiling: MaskType, floor: MaskType, walls: MaskType } | null>(null);
    const [imgWidth, setImgWidth] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [imgHeight, setImgHeight] = useState<number | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
         const fetchData = async () => {
         const formData = new FormData();
         formData.append('vectorized', 'true');
         formData.append('room_image', { uri: route.params.Image, name: 'room_image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' });
         formData.append('vectorized', 'true')
    
          const headers = new Headers();
          headers.append("Authorization", `${AUTH_TOKEN}`);
          headers.append("X-RapidAPI-Key", `${API_KEY}`);
          headers.append("X-RapidAPI-Host", 'vision-api.p.rapidapi.com');
    
          const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: formData,
            redirect: 'follow'
          };
    
          try {
            const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}`, requestOptions);
            const result = await response.json();
            if (result.vectorized_masks) {
              setVectorizedMasks(result.vectorized_masks);
            } else {
              console.log('No vectorized masks detected');
            }
  
            console.log(result);
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }

          Image.getSize(imageSource, (imgWidth, imgHeight) => {
            setImgHeight(imgHeight);
            setImgWidth(imgWidth);
    
        }, (err) => {
            
        console.error(err)
        })
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, [route.params.Image]);


    if (!route.params) {
        return null;
    }

    return {
        imageSource,
        vectorizedMasks,
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: so you have descriptions of polygons and you want to draw the polygons? no, yes, this is the first step. you need a mask for each object. that implies drawing a filled polygon.